# careers.stackoverflow.com profile picture other than the gravatar one

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page, gravatar

Can we put profile picture other than the gravatar one at careers.stackoverflow.com?

I am able to remove my gravatar picture but I am not sure if I am able to upload a new one.

Comment: Are you interested in having a field where to put your actual picture, which would be shown instead of your Gravatar?

Comment: @kiamlaluno What I would like to is take the gravatar down and upload a picture just for my profile page on careers.

Comment: I'd like to be able to upload non-Gravatar photos, too. I don't think the OPs question was limited to just monkeying around with Gravatars.

Comment: I agree with the OP, the ability to upload a picture without using Gravatar would be a nice option.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What I would do is add a new e-mail address to Gravatar specifically for Careers and attach a new picture to that.

No need for a new e-mail account. You should be able to just do this: Instead of `tugberk@example.com` create an e-mail address within Gravatar `tugberk+careers@example.com`. This is what I do to make my Gravatar at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) different than my Gravatar for the rest of the Stack Exchange network.

Unless your e-mail provider has hosed it, any messages sent to that address should get delivered to `tugberk@example.com`. (I use Gmail and it works great.)

A side effect is that you can create an e-mail filter keyed off of the `+careers` (or whatever string you use) so that you can treat such messages differently.

(This "plus-address" comes from [IETF RFC 5233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233), which refers to it as "sub-addressing" and it's been around for ages. That some e-mail providers have chosen to break it is a different issue. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags.)

Comment: Wish I could give more than one upvote for the "plus" modifier in the email address tip. That is amazing and I will be using it everywhere from now on. Thank you so so much.

Comment: I can't believe that we can't just upload a photo of our choice without having to go through the hassle of setting up a different email account. This is a small and simple change that must not be beyond the ability of SO developers given the amount of other features they write

Comment: @MattWilko This actually exists on our Q&A sites now... but that's a separate codebase and the same thing isn't available on Careers. (Yet?) Not entirely sure where the Careers team is on this feature, if it's even on the roadmap, etc. If you feel strongly about it, please put up a new post tagged [feature-request]. Thanks!

Comment: It's a shame that this is the only answer. Many (if not most) websites and organizations reject email addresses with the '+' sign as "invalid". Why can't I just upload my profile picture?