# profile picture different on one community

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, gravatar

I have the opposite problem of this post: [careers.stackoverflow.com profile picture other than the gravatar one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123111/careers-stackoverflow-com-profile-picture-other-than-the-gravatar-one) for some reason, my askubuntu.com profile picture is my facebook picture, and not my gravatar one. I can't change it to my gravatar one, and don't want my facebook picture on that site. is there a secret setting to change this? i have tried pushing my profile to all through one of the other sites...

EDIT:

Here is the difference between two of my profiles, regarding choices.
[image: profile picture selector difference between two profiles]
[image]

Comment: Weird. When you go to your askubuntu profile, Edit, and click the Change Picture link, when hovering your avatar, what do you get? This is what I see, for example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5MWKU.png

Comment: Please go [here](http://askubuntu.com/users/mylogins/current), and click "add more logins..." link. Add the provider you are using here (Google?) and this should resolve your issue, probably. :)

Comment: and if it already is in the list? (twice) do I remove it and add it again?

Comment: Hmm... no. Better wait for a dev to take a look. Something is funky with your account on askubuntu, better not mess it even more. :)

Comment: On AskUbuntu, can you try the upload option, clicking on "You can also provide a link from the web." - and using your Gravatar link? What happens when you do that?

Comment: @Oded even if it works, it will just store the current gravatar pic, but if he'll change it on gravatar, it won't change on the site. Or will it?

Comment: that may be worth testing. I'll try it later. on my way out of the door now

Comment: @ShadowWizard - it should store it as a gravatar URL and it should change when the site changes it.

Comment: @Oded so I fear it's borked, I just did it on AskUbuntu (yeah, too curious to ignore such an option ;)) and it just uploaded to i.stack.imgur.com like any other picture

Comment: So it's "wait for the developer" time...

Comment: I just realized that my username is also different?