# Allow to specify a different email address for Gravatar

Tags: feature-request, jobs, gravatar

The profile editor of Careers offers the option to use the Gravatar service to display an image (presumably a photo of the candidate). This is great, but IMHO has an important limitation: the email used to retrieve the image is always the same as the contact email. In my case (and I guess that I am not the only one) I don't have my own photo associated to my main email address, so I had to resort to specify an alternative contact email.

Suggestion: when the user clicks "Display Gravatar", show a new field labeled "Email for Gravatar" that will be initially empty. If the user keeps its this way, fine, the contact email will be used for Gravatar as usual. But if an alternative email address is supplied, this one will be used:

[image]

Comment: Related on the verge of dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168986/non-gravatar-profile-pictures-in-careers.

Comment: An alternative way to get a different Gravatar without having to resort to an alternative email address: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123114/21960

Comment: @AlE. Tried it and works prefectly, thanks! However I still think that an extra field for a Gravatar-only email, without having to resort to this kind of workarounds, is the way to go.